# Subclass of a UIView doesn't have a view property

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, swift

I've subclassed a `UIScrollView`, which happens to be a subclass of `UIView` (obviously). I'm trying to add an image to it (via a `UIImageView`), but it can't find the `view` property. So when I type this code:

```
// Called in the init() method
view.addSubView(imageView)
```

Xcode gives the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'view'
```

What's going on with this? And even when I type this code:

```
self.view.addSubView(imageView)
```

it goes the error `'<Classname>' does not have a member named 'view'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a UIView, therefore  you want to do `self.addSubview(sv)` , addSubview is a method of UIView... UIViews dont have view properties, UIViewControllers do. Here is a [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) to UIView documentation

Answer (score 0):

Since `self` itself refers to `UIView` (as `UIScrollView` is inherited from it), why would you like to have separate property named as `view`?

Use it something like
`self.addSubView(myImageView)`